# Showing Tags, Posts, Custom taxonomies dropdowns in Options panel

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've been working with WordPress Settings API to create an options page for a plugin. Everything is fine except for displaying select dropdown lists and checkbox lists for WordPress tags, posts and custom taxonomies (if exists).

For categories, I'm using `wp_dropdown_categories()`. Is there any similar function for tags, CPTs and custom taxonomies as well? If not, how can it be doable?

Answer (score 0):

For custom post type you can use the WP_Query method
like so:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'your_custom_post_type',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => 'your_custom_key',
            'value'   => 'your_custom_value',
        )
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

For more information go to the link:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters